# How to store and use a Cryptographic Seed in a database

Tags: authenticated-encryption, database, one-time-password

Companies such as Barclays use cryptographic seeds (for their PINsentry system), RSA do the same for RSA SecurID, but how do they safely secure the seeds in the database. 
With passwords you just hash it at and add a salt, but the server must know the original seed to verify the users code, the one-time password generated from the seed.

Comment: "how do they safely secure the seeds", [they don't](http://arstechnica.com/security/2011/06/rsa-finally-comes-clean-securid-is-compromised/)

Comment: They must keep them secret somehow, otherwise it's completely pointless right. If they get hacked, that's it, there done for, along with everyone who uses it

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to? RSA got hacked, they had to issue 40 million new tokens.

Comment: I've read that article before as part of my research on cryptography. It says they were compromised, but it doesn't say how it was protected, or not protected. 
I guess that's why they used passwords with RSA. But Barclays don't. But it's incredibly stupid not to protect credentials. But anyway, there must be a way to store them safely, instead of stupidly. Thanks for your comments though @mikeazo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) it's about security rather than cryptography and 2) we don't know for sure - ask the companies involved. Answers here cannot be verified unless this is public information.

Comment: I'm not saying what they actually do, as in reveal private information, I'm saying how would they do it. Besides RSA and PINsentry have already been cracked anyway, there's no secrets left, how they create there codes etc. is no secret.

Comment: The only way I could imagine doing securing seeds is by using AES, hash won't work because you won't be able to verify the OTP.

Comment: If it were me, I would encrypt the field using AES, then split the secret key among multiple (heterogeneous) servers and use multi-party computation to decrypt the values. There could be unacceptable overhead with this solution, however.

Comment: Thanks @mikeazo, finally someone with answer. I was thinking of the same thing, sure there's extra overhead, but it always requires a hell of a lot more overhead on any attacker. And by doing so, you actually add security, instead of just giving a false sense of security by not encrypting the seeds

Comment: If you are interested in having the question reopened, I suggest you look at the help center and make some updates. Then let me know and I'll reopen. Some things to avoid are open ended questions and speculation on what companies are doing to protect their data.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to encrypt a seed in a db would be to use multiparty computation and heterogeneous computing (multiple core systems). The only other way would be to store them in plaintext, e.g. in a shadow password (non-public file).

Comment: I don't know if it is correct to say that this is the best way. Just a way. Other possible ways to do it include using a TPM or simply using secret sharing to spread out the seed to multiple machines.